# How to find value in the google sheets using the api , for Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get the row and column number of the cell where the value exists. I did find there is find method in python but I wanted the same thing in node JS .
My data for which I will be searching  will be unique.

Comment: What have you tried? Please put the code that you have tried in the question.

Comment: I haven't tried as I was not able to move forward.with any particular code.

Comment: a simple Google search led me to this: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-javascriptnode-js.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but it didn't seem to have what I am looking for.